# Why are editing options missing for one question?

Tags: support, editing

I was editing questions and answers this morning and came across a [new question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18596/d7-multiple-user-type-table-question) in which tags and editing options were not available.  Other questions have all options, but not this one.

Nevermind! Kiamlaluno was editing it at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

When there is already a pending proposed edit, users who don't have the privilege of editing any post don't see the "edit" link. (The image is a link to the question's revision page.)

[image: screenshot]

Until the proposed edit is approved, or rejected, those users will not be able to see the "edit" link.

The other reason for not seeing that link is that the queue used to contain all the proposed edits is full; when it happens, no more proposed edits are accepted, and the "edit" link is not visible anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info!